# Why does Request["whatever"] return the cookie value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, query-string, form-post

From what I understand:

`Request.Form["whatever"]` will return the value from the form POST collection
`Request.QueryString["whatever"]` will return the value from the QueryString collection (or GET)
`Request["whatever"]` will return the value from the POST collection (if it exists) or the QueryString collection, in that order

However, I have seen that if there's a cookie called "whatever" and there is no value for "whatever" found in either POST or QueryString collections, the cookie value will be returned.

Am I mistaken or is this in fact what happens by design in ASP.Net MVC 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.item(v=vs.110).aspx):

> gets the specified object from the Cookies, Form, QueryString, or ServerVariables collections

So yes, it is very much by design that `Request["whatever"]` returns a cookie value.

Comment: (facepalm) - sorry, I'm not sure how I missed that before (having been developing web applications for the past 15 years!) - thanks!